# JVM crash at CompilerThread

Tags: java, crash, jvm, jvm-hotspot

My java application is crashing almost consistently when trying to compile a specific method (it's always the same method), with SIGSEGV:

```
 A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:

  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00002aaaab6642a5, pid=8348, tid=1087596864

 JRE version: 6.0_16-b01
 Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (14.2-b01 mixed mode linux-amd64 )
 Problematic frame:
 V  [libjvm.so+0x5332a5]

 An error report file with more information is saved as:
 hs_err_pid8348.log

 If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
   http://java.sun.com/webapps/bugreport/crash.jsp
```

The crash log (interesting parts...):

```
 A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:

  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00002aaaab6642a5, pid=8348, tid=1087596864

 JRE version: 6.0_16-b01
 Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (14.2-b01 mixed mode linux-amd64 )
 Problematic frame:
 V  [libjvm.so+0x5332a5]

 If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
   http://java.sun.com/webapps/bugreport/crash.jsp

---------------  T H R E A D  ---------------

Current thread (0x00002aab1f7ac800):  JavaThread "CompilerThread0" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=8694, stack(0x0000000040c36000,0x00000000
40d37000)]
```

I tried to create a core dump and connect to it, but I couldn't find the CompilerThread there (maybe it's been killed be

Answer (score 2):

Post the entire page (w/ the extra info on the libraries) with the stack and more if can get. You can't see ANY thread if you see the core dump.

If the problem includes zlib (ZipEntry), you are partyly out of luck... 
It's a very annoying **BUG** in zlip with very very bold and it occurs if the zip (jar) is changed after being open. I still wonder why Sun/Oracle uses a native library for zip processing since doing it in purely java is more stable and ... 2 times faster (performance wise).

Comment: @bestsss what do you mean by ZipEntry - libzip.so?

Comment: yeah (i do mean so to please the char. length)

Comment: @bestsss: do you have a link that describes this issue?

Comment: @ekeren: I have crash dumps with, though and perfectly reproducible behavior however sun considers it: "11-Closed, Not Reproducible, bug"
http://bugs.sun.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=6366468

Comment: @bestsss: it's also particularly sad that they're using a native *zlib* because it has also already been the root cause for at least one security issue (buffer overflow IIRC), which would have been impossible should they have been using a Java-written one...  But maybe there's some Catch-22 here, dunno, haven't really looked into that.

Comment: @SyntaxT3rr0r: no, there is no catch, converting to full java.util.zip written in java is entirely possible. Probably, the next time I have some free time I will convert our (company) application servers to use.

Comment: @SyntaxT3rr0r: back in the day I suppose it was a major performance issue, now native zlib is slower on the field tests than jzlib. Calling non-inlined JNI code (any custom library) is not quick at all.

Answer (score 2):

**Manually optimize the method involved.**

`Current thread (0x00002aab1f7ac800):  JavaThread "CompilerThread0" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=8694, stack(0x0000000040c36000,0x00000000
40d37000)]`

Just below this line, you should see the specific method that the hotspot engine was trying to optimize.  You have likely hit some code in hotspot that has some problems.  It will be very hard to determine exactly what code was hit and why.

I've had this problem occur, and I solved it.  The method involved was written in a very non-optimized fashion.  Unnecessary data structures were created, extra loops were added, and also extra variables created and used only once.  I iteratively optimized more and more of this method until it finally didn't throw the exception after the final iteration which was pretty low-level almost nit-picky optimizations.

I believe that in the end, there was a bug in some sort of byte-code optimization routine that was being triggered in the hotspot engine.  There's almost no way of knowing exactly what was happening.  But I think that by optimizing the code manually, I optimized the byte-code in such a way that the hotspot engine no longer ran the buggy routine.

I know that this is nothing definite, but I hope that my story can help you and future visitors.  Best of luck!

Comment: How did you manually optimize the method using JIT? Can u plz let me know. I am also facing same problem.

Comment: I did not use JIT.  In my case, the method mentioned in the next line was a method in my library which was being compiled.  I optimized that method by removing unnecessary code and loops.  If the method already appeared optimized, I would try breaking things down in a different way - tweaking the algorithm so that the steps would be slightly different.

Answer (score 0):

JRE version 6.0_16 is rather old. I recommend upgrading to the current JRE, there's a very good chance this crash will have been fixed.

Comment: This is the newest version i've got in my environment... can't upgrade at the moment.

Comment: @duduamar: Then I'm afraid you're stuck with the problem. You can't debug this, unless you want to go into the binary internals of the JVM (and you really don't). Upgrading the JVM is the only solution to this.

Comment: @skafmman: do you know of an open bug in 6.0_16 that might explain this?

Comment: @ekeren: Not specifically, no. It's the only thing I can suggest, however, and it often works.

Answer (score 0):

If this is an option, you can exclude the method that is causing the crash from runtime by adding this parameter to java executable call
`-XX:CompileCommand=exclude,com/path/to/class/in/Jar$InnerClassIfAny.methodName`

The name of the class and method that cause the crash can be found in the crash report (hs_err_pidxxxx.log) right above the

`---------------  P R O C E S S  ---------------`

mark.

Note: on a Unix environment, the inner class (if any) should be escaped like this `\$` instead of `$`.